# Robolectric unit tests build.os version returns incorrectly?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Hi i am trying to run a unit test that executes a code block if the build version is 23 or more but when i call the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT it always returns 1?

here is the unit test code:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
public class Test {

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
         //test some block of code

   }

}
```

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to run a unit test that goes inside a block of code that checks the Android build version. It's not working. It returns int value of despite me specifying the Android build version on the top of the class inside the config annotation

Comment: What version of Robolectric do you use? Because `emulateSdk` is for 2.x and 3.x is already year released.

Comment: Also found this https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/277

Answer (score 1):

From the explanations here (https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/277) you run on JVM and that is probably why **Robolectric** is not changing this constant according to emulated SDK. Which is actually strange.

But apparently, in that thread is also workaround how to test it:

```
ReflectionHelpers.setStaticField(Build.VERSION.class, "SDK_INT", 18);
```